# 'if' in array w/ Shell Script

Tags: arrays, linux, shell, if-statement

I have an array with different values, and if the value is 3 (integer) this value will be exchanged for 999 (integer). But I have a syntax problem in the 'if' block of the array.

**The correct return would be: 1 999 5 7 9 999**

```
vetor=(1 3 5 7 9 3)
for i in ${vetor[*]}
do
    if [[ ${vetor[i]} = 3 ]]; then
        ${vetor[i]} = 999
    fi
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: `vetor[i]=999` there are no spaces surrounding `'='` when used for assignment. You do not use `$` (dereference) when making assignment. Also understand `[[ ${vetor[i]} = 3 ]]` makes a string comparison, while `[[ ${vetor[i]} -eq 3 ]]` makes a numeric comparison. Changing `vetor[i]` does not change the loop variable `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the correct output in Bash:

```
vetor=(1 3 5 7 9 3);
for i in ${!vetor[*]};
do
     if [[ ${vetor[i]} -eq 3 ]]; then
         vetor[i]=999;
     fi;
     echo ${vetor[i]};
done
```

I added `!` in the for loop expression to get the indices of `vetor` instead of the values, and I removed the ${} around the assignment in the if condition (this was giving "if 3 is not a typo" warnings). Also changed the echo to get the value at vetor[i] instead of printing the index.